# Blocking all other network calls until a particular network call is over in RxAndroid

Tags: mvvm, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-android

I have an mobile app that fetches data from multiple network calls. All those network calls have a common query parameter, say portalId and I would get that portalId from another network call.

Since I make all the network calls parallel, there may occur a situation when one of the request call may hit the network without that portalId. So I need to block all the network calls before the portalId is fetched.

How can I achieve this using RxAndroid?

Comment: Well there are multiple ways... without any code is hard to figure it out, but one solution can be ``flatMap``. You flat map the answer of the call that gives you ``portalId`` to the other calls that receive it.

Comment: @Fred - Won't that be like, everytime I make a network call I need to hit the other network call that would yield me the portalId??
My scenario is I need to get the portalId from network and save it locally and use the same for other network calls. But the reason I want to block other network calls is there might be situation, when multiple network calls occur when there is no portalId saved locally.

Comment: well then you might consider implementing an okhttp interceptor that checks if you have a ``portalId`` stored and if not, does the call before letting the current call proceed. This can be put into the okhttp client and you only need to do it there. All calls will used this interceptor if created from the same retrofit instance

Comment: @Fred - I found FlatMap to be useful for this scenario, Thank you for your response, and sorry for the late reply.